# Reference request: Détailed explanation why the Grassmannian scheme represents the Grassmannian functor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, grassmannians, representable-functors

Similar questions have been asked on this site, including by myself, but none of these have been given a satisfying answer.

The question is: Why does the Grassmannian scheme represent the Grassmannian functor? I have seen many books and articles about this, and they all treat it as an exercise to the reader. I am willing to admit that I may be too stupid for the exercise, but is there a textbook or survey article that explains this in détail? I mean it is somehow obvious, but I'd like to see it worked out. Please, if possible, no stacks-project or EGA.

Comment: I think there is no explanation that is more detailed than the one in EGA I (2nd edition).

Comment: I suspect that the reason for leaving it as an exercise is that the details are boring.

Comment: The Grassmannian is a special case of a quot scheme. The construction of quot schemes is done in detail in Nitsure's article in the volume 'FGA explained' (but I agree that this might be an overkill...)

Comment: In fact, what is "the" Grassmann scheme? You can construct it as a quotient of a linear group, or as a subscheme of projective space via Plücker equations, or by glueing affine pieces (the latter being essentially the EGA way). The proof will be different in each case.

Comment: ...there is also Görtz-Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, p. 209.